# how to re-install zlib1g_1.2.11 from root access

Tags: root, boot-repair, backlight, zlib

First, writing from mobile as Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is failing to boot. I have access to 'root@user:~#' from the recovery menu. I have updated the backlight setting (systemctl mask systemd-backlight@backlight:acpi_video0) as posted on another thread..thankyou.. which uncovered the missing 'zlib' files and are discussed in another post BUT i would like some help IF re-installing zlib files is possible from root access. I have downloaded the files from Ubuntu.org on usb.. can someone help with root access code/script to work this problem.. MUCH APPRECIATED (we are all learning.. especially newbs!)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the file available, then you can do this:

1. Copy the file locally, perhaps to `/root`
2. `tar -xvf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz`
3. `cd zlib-1.2.11`
4. `sudo -s`
5. `./configure; make; make install`
6. `cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
7. `ln -s -f /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.11/lib libz.so.1`

Once that's done, you can remove the source files

1. `cd /root`
2. `rm -Rf zlib-1.2.11`

That should do it for you.

Comment: Mucho Gracias Matigo!! I resourced step 1., followed exact script, access my system! Really great :) checked the model-install script, indeed (now understandeably) formats libraries ALSO as in other stack threads (zlib files) cleaner to Ubuntu LiveCd/usb, i will do IF i now iinet pckges working again.PLZ!! Still searching on old mobile..completed few checks from terminal, appears (from boot fail errors) 'ppa.launchpad.net' fails.. dbus.connection. just get last step to  iinet, someones help, then i can reload ubuntu.iso, AND re-collect all my steps and answer this question to help others! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Matigo supplied the above script to access my OS again, which is available in other threads (invest in thorough searching!) and hopefully this additional QA will give the newb confidence ;)

First, Matigo's step ..
'1. Copy the file locally, perhaps to /root
..is nicely provided [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-and-unmount-file-systems-in-linux/) and below..

If you have the [file available](http://Fossies%20downloads:%20/linux/misc/%20zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz%20%20(tar.bz2%7Ctar.xz%7Czip)) (get now for following steps but READ ALL FIRST), then you can do this:

So..
Boot up..scroll down boot menu to 'Advanced Options'..enter Scroll down to 'generic (recovery mode)'..enter
GNU GRUB menu ..scroll down to 'root'..enter..enter..
TERMINAL..which you can now delivery packages/tar.gz to the OS and recover your system

In the terminal enter..

`lsblk` #identify your usb..usually 'sdb' at bottom of list.. google if not sure.. if it does NOT appear then the usb possibly needs correct formatting for the OS to read.. which means you will have to re-format, and re-save the tar.gz file to the usb to then upload through the linux recovery mode /root

`sudo mkdir -p /media/usb` #make a place in your system (directory/folder) that the computer can talk to your usb from..

`sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/usb` #connect (sudo mount) the usb (/dev/sdb) to the computer OS (/media/usb)... file system in usb to file system in OS

`cp /media/sdb/zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz /` #cp (sopy) /media/sdbzlib-1.2.11.tar.gz (the tar zlib in the usb) / (to the root.. ubuntu OS)

`sudo umount /dev/sdb1` #unmount the usb so you dont corrupt the filing system!!

now that the tar.gz is IN THE OS.. run below to unzip in OS and 'reboot' (final step) to re-gain access to your system..

```
tar -xvf zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz
cd zlib-1.2.11
sudo -s
./configure; make; make install
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
ln -s -f /usr/local/lib/libz.so.1.2.11/lib libz.so.1
```

Once that's done, you can remove the source files

```
cd /root
rm -Rf zlib-1.2.11
```

and begin the week long research and repair of..

1. configure iinet connections... (`ping -c 6 google.com` to test if `sudo apt-get update` fails/return ERROR to accessing ubuntu.org for re-install of vital libraries) ..THEN ..either take the struggle and try manual recovery (2., 3. below) ..OR JUST CREATE A NEW LIVE! BOOT.. i read it earlier and now see its the BEST OPTION as you can choose to save your files from the crashed system and reload them in  new install XD...
2. `sudo apt-get update && upgrade`, enabling some packages/libraries that uncover further errors that can be investigated and solutions applied to repeat update && upgrade, multiple stages and repeats!
3. final stage of error sourcing and `sudo apt-get update –fix-missing` [repairs](https://linuxhint.com/apt_get_fix_missing_broken_packages/) to have the OS to the exact state as previous (internet, sudo apt-get, gitlab through R-Studio, and many more.. [here](https://linuxhint.com/apt_get_fix_missing_broken_packages/))

I hope this helps as even though i recovered, it's probably best to leave each error and code to the experts on here!