# Unfreeze upgrade on 18.04LTS (found linux image..found intrd image)

Tags: upgrade, partial-upgrade

sudo apt-get update && upgrade for 18.04 LTS, after re-installing 'zlib-1.2.11.tar.gz' [how to re-install zlib1g_1.2.11 from root access](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1297676/how-to-re-install-zlib1g-1-2-11-from-root-access/1297686#1297686) to recover from boot-fail likely started from shared library file code within build.sh file

current freeze point below..

```
Setting up grub-pc (2.02-2ubuntu8.20) ...
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-118-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-118-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-117-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-117-generic
```

.. i do not want to execute anything in my attempt, that will further corrupt the OS.. it has been a long road back!

Answer (score 0):

appears as 'thinking time'..overnight the updates progressed after hours of apparent frozen (blinking cursor) activity.. some easy explanations at diagnosing errors [here](https://geekflare.com/linux-performance-commands/) [here](https://opensource.com/article/18/12/troubleshooting-hardware-problems-linux) .. good luck newbs!
thanks OrgM for nudging my etiquette ;)

Comment: maybe this is also fixed/achieved through @heynemma fixes.. as found in other 'boot-fail' instances..   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1341426/sudo-apt-get-upgrade-e-dpkg-was-interrupted-you-must-manuallly-run-sudo-dpkg