# sudo apt-get upgrade.. E: dpkg was interrupted you must manuallly run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem

Tags: boot, upgrade

Background..
18.04 LTS, Lenovo G50, many previous boot fails (+4yr old hardware)

OS booted normal, opened internet (mozilla) and browser was not 'normal', press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
to open terminal and immediately run..

```
sudo apt-get-update
```

to determine if OS is at 'optimal' functioning' condition

so, above command returned ..

> ```
> Hit:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease            
> Get:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]
> ```

which is 'good' at this point as the OS is connecting to the iinet and 'grub' (core operating procedures) are functioning, however..

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

which is the best chance of 'fixing' some out-of-date/corrupted boot files returned..

> ```
> E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt..
> ```

(basically the upgrade failed and `/var/lib` files were locked..)

> ```
> W: Problem un-linking the file..
> ```

so THIS IS A VERY DELICATE STEP.. the OS has failed to correctly upgrade (download) codes/systems that allow your OS to function normal/optimal...
and has NOW locked the systems that connect to the iinet and allow you to search for solutions/download OS fixes (update && upgrade etc..)

IMMEDIATELY determine/conduct OS/internet-connection repair

OS/iinet failure/'not-normal operation must be investigated/repaired BEFORE any further operations OTHERWISE user will likely 'chase' (wild-goose-chase) many further links/procedures-in-OS-repair before simply ensuring a correct boot is performed and OS is functioning correctly..

@heynemma solved previous boot-fails with `fsck` commands

"my" error message from the above `sudo apt-get upgrade` returned..

> ```
>  E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt..
> ```

(basically the upgrade failed and `/var/lib` files were locked..)

> ```
>  W: Problem un-linking the file..
> ```

> ```
> .. must use sudo dpkg --configure -a
> ```

again attempt..

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

continues to return..

> ```
>  E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt..
> ```

(basically the upgrade failed and `/var/lib` files were locked..)

> ```
> W: Problem un-linking the file..
> .. must use sudo dpkg --configure -a
> ```

so some links direct you to assess the running processes causing a 'possible' freeze [check running processes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424754/how-to-solve-errors-in-apt-get-update-in-ubuntu/424762)..

```
ps -A | grep apt
```

and some links direct you to remove the 'locked' files...

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

but in my instance that returns..

> ```
> E: unable to unlock read/write ..
> ```

so following @heynemma 'fix' sources/sites/ask-ubuntu-links..

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo fsck /dev/sda6
```

(sda6 is my ubuntu drive)

```
systemctl reboot
```

and re-run these commands to 'refresh' the system after the grub (core boot procedure) is 'likely' repaired..

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo fsck -y /dev/sda6
```

(-y automatically answers 'yes' to all questions of 'repair drive.. ?' .. but the first instance is best to see 'what' your repairing at each instance/question..)

```
systemctl reboot
```

..some useful commands to ID the boot failure but difficult to understand for new users [here](https://www.tecmint.com/dmesg-commands/) ..

```
dmesg | tail -100
```

[or](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units)

```
systemctl
```

I understand this is @heynemma fix and is well published for many (likely almost all) problems on Ubu18.04 boot fails.. but for newbs the step-by-step helps in 'getting' the OS back to having the system start and iinet functioning back to 'normal' so that confidence is built in the user towards their ubuOS for function and further investigations of operations

Comment: The lockfile is there to protect you. Before tinkering with the lockfile, you must be **absolutely** sure that no other apt-related process is running. Not Unattended Upgrades. Not Ubuntu Software. Not Synaptic. Not apt in a different window. Many times here, the problem turns out to simply be that a different apt process was running, and the user didn't realize it. Or the user simply didn't realize that only one apt process can run at a time.

Comment: Did you do `sudo dpkg --configure -a`? The computer boots, yes? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Yes, I followed each instruction as directed first by errors (E: ..) returned after the 'upgrade' failed but NO.. 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' did NOT work, then followed a number of threads (mainly from askubuntu.com first), and then other website tips which included trying to clear/remove caches and/or log files etc (rm ... / apt clean)..BUT what did work was the combination and specifically REPEATING the commands 'sudo apt-get clean' (cache cleaning?) and 'sudo fsck -y /dev/sda6'  to my ubuOS disk (sda6)..THEN the update && upgrade ran smooth..which is MUCH easier than prev. repair attempts